# Create file for new user

Tags: users

I'm creating custom build of Ubuntu with some installed packages.
My question is how to put a file on desktop automatically after creating new user? For example something.txt containing some text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put the file in directory

```
/etc/skel/Desktop/
```

in the chrooted version of you custom build. If the directory does not exist yet you need to create it. `/etc/skel/` is used to create the "skeleton" for the new users `/home/$USER/` directories and content.

Comment: The skel structure is always in English, no matter what language you use. So I don't think there's need to use scripts. If you put a file in /etc/skel/Desktop/ when a new user logs in he/she will have it in /home/$USER/Escriptori. I'm using the catalan desktop interface and it works.